# Differential Equation, linear or non-linear?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, differential

I am new to the area of solving differential equations, and I came across the following differential equation and was wondering whether it was linear or non-linear:

$dy/dx= x^3 + y^3$

I would have said that the equation is non-linear, as the dependant variable being multiplied by itself three times, but the book says that the differential equation is linear?

Just out of curiosity, would the following integral be linear:

$d^4y/dx^4= x^3 + y^3$

Cheers.

Comment: I would have called either equation nonlinear solely due to the $y^3$.

Answer (score 3):

A differential equation is called **linear** if it is **linear with respect to the unknown function and its derivatives**. For a first order equationt this means that the equation has the form:
$$
y'+f(x)y+g(x)=0
$$
Your equation has the form:
$$
y'-y^3-x^3=0
$$
so it is  not linear.

You can see the same for the other equation.

Comment: Don't you mean "and its derivative*s*"?

Comment: Cheers, thanks for the general format, this will help me with other problems too.

Comment: Yes! Typo from my bad english.....

Answer (score 2):

Both of the differential equations you present are nonlinear, for the reason you cite: the presence of the $y^{3}$ term.

To add a bit more just for clarity:
\begin{eqnarray}
&\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = x^{3}+y&\text{ is linear,}\\[6pt]
&\frac{\mathrm{d}^{4}y}{\mathrm{d}x^{4}} = x^{3}+y&\text{ is linear,}\\[6pt]
&\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = x^{3}+y^{3}&\text{ is nonlinear,}\\[6pt]
&\frac{\mathrm{d}^{4}y}{\mathrm{d}x^{4}} = x^{3}+y^{3}&\text{ is nonlinear,}\\[6pt]
&\text{and also, as a bonus example,}&\\[6pt]
&\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)^{4} = x^{3}+y&\text{ is nonlinear.}\\
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Cheers, I thought so, the book turned out to be wrong all along.